# How can I access the SecurityContext in a MethodInterceptor?

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, spring-aop

I'm working on a Spring MVC application with a Spring Security setup that authenticates an Active Directory user over LDAP. I'm trying to set up AOP to log each controller method that's called. I've got everything working and I can intercept the method.. but I can't seem to access the SecurityContext to get the username of the logged in user who's executing the method.

UserInvokedMethodLogger.java

```
public class UserInvokedMethodLogger implements MethodInterceptor
{
    private SecurityContext security = SecurityContextHolder.getContext();

    @Override
    public Object invoke(MethodInvocation interceptedMethod) throws Throwable
    {
        long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
        Object result = interceptedMethod.proceed();
        long end = System.currentTimeMillis();

        String dbgMessage =
                (security.getAuthentication() != null)
                    ? "User '" + security.getAuthentication().getName() + "' called method '"
                    : "Unauthenticated user called method '"
                + interceptedMethod.getMethod().getName()
                + "' which executed in " + (end - start) + "ms.";

        System.out.println(dbgMessage);
        return result;
    }
}
```

Even when I'm logged in the output is always "Unauthenticated user".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to call SecurityContextHolder.getContext() during each method invocation. Just remove your `private SecurityContext security` property and use SecurityContextHolder.getContext() directly.